# FlowGear IMAP Watcher Node

Tags: flowgear

I've configured an IMAP Watcher Node to point at a Gmail-based account.  The Test of the connection returns success.  However, when I run the node in the design tool, I get this error:

> IMAP Watcher(v1.0.1.6): An operation requiring Environment permission
>   was denied.  Check Node Connection and properties or consider using a
>   DropPoint.

I imagine the "permission" it needs is to move the processed message from the Watch folder to the Processed folder.  It's connecting to the mailbox with the credentials of the mailbox owner.  Why would permissions be denied?

Please help.

Comment: This Node needs to be run at a DropPoint in order to have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Ok thanks that worked.  If you make your comment the answer I can check it as such.